# VSCode Debug opens stl_map.h when attempting to step into function to debug it

Tags: c++, function, visual-studio-code, graph-theory, vscode-debugger

I am attempting to debug a graph function that starts at one vertex and ends at a destination vertex upon finding it via a FS (First Search) algo. Upon calling the function during debug mode, the debugger opens stl_map.h (I assume it does this because the graph (vertices and edges) have been implemented within a map.

The parameters of the function are (map, startPerson, endPerson). I pass a map, and the two people parameters as follows (name of the function is bfsFacebook):

```
for (;;) {
        cout << endl << "Enter the name of the starting person:\n";
        getline(cin, startingPerson);
        if (IS_QUIT(startingPerson))
            break;
        if (everyone.count(startingPerson) == 0) {
            cout << "Invalid starting name.";
            continue;
        }
        cout << endl << "Enter the name of the ending person:\n";
        getline(cin, endingPerson);
        if (IS_QUIT(endingPerson))
            break;
        if (everyone.count(endingPerson) == 0) {
            cout << "Invalid ending name.";
            continue;
        }
        //Breath-First search from starting node to end node (starting vertext to end vertex)
        if (bfsFacebook(everyone, everyone[startingPerson], everyone[endingPerson]) == true) {
            cout << "Path found between " << startingPerson << " and " << endingPerson << endl;
        } else {
            cout << "Path Not Found between " << startingPerson << " and " << endingPerson << endl;
        }
        
    }
    cout << "Exiting..." << endl;
```

Here is the actual function:

```
bool bfsFacebook(map<string, Person> everyone, Person &startingPerson, Person &endingPerson) {
    
    startingPerson.visited = true;
    if (startingPerson.name == endingPerson.name && startingPerson.visited == true)
        return true;

    for (string somePerson : startingPerson.friends) {
        if (everyone[somePerson].visited == false && bfsFacebook(everyone, everyone[somePerson], endingPerson)) {
            return true;
        }
            
    }

    return false;
}
```

Is there any particular reason why stepping into the function during debugging does not send me to the actual function?

*If my question is not detailed enough, please let me know.*

Answer (score 0):

The call line:

```
 bfsFacebook(everyone, everyone[startingPerson], everyone[endingPerson])
```

Starts by resolving the arguments before calling `bfsFacebook` with them.

You have two calls to `map<string, Person>::operator[](const string&)` which shall be done to resolve `everyone[startingPerson]` and `everyone[endingPerson]`, so the next executed line in your program is in `std::map`

---

The `map<Key, Value>::operator[](const Key&)` may be optimized depending on the build, but in debug it's more likely to be present in the code.

As the `std::map` has been instantiated for `<string, Person>` by your own code, the debugger has no reason not to step in a function which existence is your responsibility.